# Why is this plywood missing the grades?

Tags: flooring, plywood

I went to Home Depot to find some 3/4" tongue and groove plywood for a flooring project and what I saw was this:

```
RATED STURD-I-FLOOR
24oc
T&G NET WIDTH 47-1/2"
EXPOSURE 1
--282--
RS1-07 UNDERLAYMENT
SANDED FACE
PRP-108
23/32 CATEGORY
```

The "sanded face" bit makes me think this is an "A" grade face but it doesn't make any mention of the rear face. How can I make heads or tails of the grades on this plywood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sturd-I-Floor** is the "Standard/Grade" in this case. It's a little murky for anyone old enough to expect the A-B-C grading. But it's designed for the job you want to do.

http://www.performancepanels.com/single.cfm?content=app_pp_group2